# Square Connect API Chargebacks/Disputes

Tags: square-connect

If a merchant experiences a dispute / chargeback, where does that appear in the [Square Connect API](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api)? As a refund? As a negative payment? Is there another endpoint specifically for this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this gap in the documentation. I've updated this answer with the definitive settlement entry type.

Events like chargebacks are reflected in the `entries` of `Settlement` objects returned by the [List](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#get-settlements) and [Retrieve Settlement](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#get-settlementid) endpoints. All chargeback-related [settlement entries](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#datatype-settlemententry) have the `type` `HOLD_ADJUSTMENT`. These entries can indicate the placing of a hold on disputed funds, or the subsequent release of a hold if a chargeback is won by the merchant.

Chargebacks are *not* reflected in payment- or refund-related endpoints.

Comment: Since disputes can only go back 60 days for _Billing Errors_ and _Quality of Goods & Services_; this doesn't seem like a terrible solution. Simply grab the last 60 days of Settlements, and loop through the entries looking for the **TBD** `type` of `CHARGE`. However, since _Unauthorized Amount Billing Errors_ have no time limit, how would one account for this? Going back indefinitely?

Please talk to the engineers about a special endpoint for this, given the lack of time limits!

Do you know what type of `SettlementEntry` objects represent a dispute yet?